# cannot read property 'Api' of undefined to load responsive datatable .js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am trying to implementing child row in datatable..as 
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html
 but now i am facing an error **cannot read property 'Api' of undefined**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxBAN.jpg)

custom.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 'tr'
        }
    },
    columnDefs: [ {
        className: 'control',
        orderable: false,
        targets:   0
    } ],
    order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
   } );
    } );
```

index.html.erb

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>8422</td>
        </tr>

.....
```

now what can i do?

Comment: Please write your code what you have tried

Comment: custom.js $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   0
        } ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
    } );
} );datatable

Comment: <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>

Comment: Look at bellow working answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   0
        } ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
    } );
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>6224</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
                <td>4804</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
                <td>9608</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
                <td>6200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
                <td>2360</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya</td>
                <td>Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
                <td>1667</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jena</td>
                <td>Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
                <td>3814</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
                <td>9497</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Charde</td>
                <td>Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
                <td>6741</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Haley</td>
                <td>Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
                <td>3597</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tatyana</td>
                <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
                <td>1965</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
                <td>1581</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
                <td>3059</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gloria</td>
                <td>Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
                <td>1721</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bradley</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
                <td>2558</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dai</td>
                <td>Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
                <td>2290</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jenette</td>
                <td>Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
                <td>1937</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Yuri</td>
                <td>Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
                <td>6154</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Caesar</td>
                <td>Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
                <td>8330</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Doris</td>
                <td>Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
                <td>3023</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Angelica</td>
                <td>Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
                <td>5797</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
                <td>8822</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
                <td>9239</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brenden</td>
                <td>Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
                <td>1314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fiona</td>
                <td>Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
                <td>2947</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shou</td>
                <td>Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
                <td>8899</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michelle</td>
                <td>House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
                <td>2769</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Suki</td>
                <td>Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
                <td>6832</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Prescott</td>
                <td>Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
                <td>3606</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
                <td>2860</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Martena</td>
                <td>Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
                <td>8240</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Unity</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
                <td>5384</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Howard</td>
                <td>Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
                <td>7031</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hope</td>
                <td>Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
                <td>6318</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Vivian</td>
                <td>Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
                <td>9422</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Timothy</td>
                <td>Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
                <td>7580</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
                <td>1042</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
                <td>2120</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bruno</td>
                <td>Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
                <td>6222</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sakura</td>
                <td>Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
                <td>9383</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Thor</td>
                <td>Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
                <td>8327</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Finn</td>
                <td>Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
                <td>2927</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Serge</td>
                <td>Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
                <td>8352</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
                <td>7439</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
                <td>4389</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
                <td>3431</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
                <td>3990</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
                <td>1016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
                <td>6733</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
                <td>8196</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>6373</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>5384</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
                <td>4226</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This code working for me..
Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/yJQaap) link

Comment: @user6394357 Copy this entire code and test it will work for you

Comment: no sir there is same issue datatable are comming but chield row is not comming.........

Comment: Can you please tell me you code on any fiddle or codespan

Comment: no i am trying your code in notepad++,and another way is ruby on rails in locally in sublime text

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with the same issue, **the fix I found was quite simple**: You need to reorganize the scripts you applying to your code so fixedColumns.min.js always comes after jquery.dataTables.min.js and your own created JS file last. 
example:

```
#The script version or source(cdn or local) may vary, just pay attention for jquery.dataTables.min.js and dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.1/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a logical answer. must be maintain this order which one mention above by @stas sorokin .

Comment: I value your appreciation @prakashkumar and delighted this helped you and others